# Parse Array in Object in Array in Dart / Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a REST Service I like to consume, but I do not know how to parse that JSON to an Object.

My JSON looks like that:

```
[
  {
    "types": {
      "KEYWORD": "STRING"
    },
    "displaynames": {
      "KEYWORD": "Keyword"
    },
    "rows": [
      {
        "KEYWORD": "Test 1"
      },
      {
        "KEYWORD": "Test 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

That is my object I created from that:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Todo> welcomeFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Todo>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Todo.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeToJson(List<Todo> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Todo {
  Todo({
    required this.types,
    required this.displaynames,
    required this.rows,
  });

  Displaynames types;
  Displaynames displaynames;
  List<Displaynames> rows;

  factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Todo(
        types: Displaynames.fromJson(json["types"]),
        displaynames: Displaynames.fromJson(json["displaynames"]),
        rows: List<Displaynames>.from(
            json["rows"].map((x) => Displaynames.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "types": types.toJson(),
        "displaynames": displaynames.toJson(),
        "rows": List<dynamic>.from(rows.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Displaynames {
  Displaynames({
    required this.keyword,
  });

  String keyword;

  factory Displaynames.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Displaynames(
        keyword: json["KEYWORD"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "KEYWORD": keyword,
      };
}
```

I try Loading the JSON and Display like that by using the pull_to_refresh Package.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pull_to_refresh_flutter3/pull_to_refresh_flutter3.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:user_portal/model/todo.dart';

class TodoRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoRoute({super.key});

  @override
  State<TodoRoute> createState() => _TodoRouteState();
}

class _TodoRouteState extends State<TodoRoute> {
  late List<Todo> todoList = [];
  final RefreshController refreshController =
      RefreshController(initialRefresh: true);

  Future<bool> fetchTodo() async {
    const String jsonstr =
        '[  {    "types": {      "KEYWORD": "STRING"    },    "displaynames": {      "KEYWORD": "Keyword"    },    "rows": [      {        "KEYWORD": "Test 1"      },      {        "KEYWORD": "Test 2"      }    ]  }]';
    todoList = (json.decode(jsonstr) as List)
        .map((data) => Todo.fromJson(data))
        .toList();
    setState(() {});

    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Todo'),
      ),
      body: SmartRefresher(
        controller: refreshController,
        enablePullUp: true,
        onRefresh: () async {
          final result = await fetchTodo();
          if (result) {
            refreshController.refreshCompleted();
          } else {
            refreshController.refreshFailed();
          }
        },
        onLoading: () async {
          final result = await fetchTodo();
          if (result) {
            refreshController.loadComplete();
          } else {
            refreshController.loadFailed();
          }
        },
        child: ListView.separated(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: todoList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(todoList[0].rows[index].keyword),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But the Only Item I get is the Test 1 Item not the Test 2 Item and I do not know where to look further for that Problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this way it's so easy...

add this method in your TOdo model

```
 static List< Todo > fromList(json) {
List< Todo > tempList = [];
try {
  json.forEach((element) {
    tempList.add(Todo.fromJson(element));
  });
  return tempList;
} catch (e) {
  return tempList;
}
 }
```

change this function

```
Future<bool> fetchTodo() async {
const String jsonstr =
    '[  {    "types": {      "KEYWORD": "STRING"    },    
  "displaynames": {      "KEYWORD": "Keyword"    },    "rows": [      {        
 "KEYWORD": "Test 1"      },      {        "KEYWORD": "Test 2"      }    
]  
 }]';
Map data = json.decode(jsonstr);

todoList = Todo.fromList(data);
setState(() {});

return true;
}
```

Comment: Your Answer looks simple. Thank you very much. I do not want to only copy and paste some code bricks. I would like to understand what I do, so can you explain why you're using that catch(e) inside your fromList function and do not do any error handling, instead give away the templist either?

Comment: yes. I can, I return the list in the catch part for handling the if we have some error during the parsing JSON or API calling in that time I m returning an empty list and on another UI  side I am always handling three views like 
1. loading state
2. data view 
3. empty view
so that it will give us to empty view 

the second option is that we can not return the empty list if we have to show an error message so just throw an error in the catch part.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `fetchTodo()` to this:

```
Future<bool> fetchTodo() async {
    const String jsonstr =
        '[  {    "types": {      "KEYWORD": "STRING"    },    "displaynames": {      "KEYWORD": "Keyword"    },    "rows": [      {        "KEYWORD": "Test 1"      },      {        "KEYWORD": "Test 2"      }    ]  }]';
    
    todoList = welcomeFromJson(jsonstr);//<--- add this

    setState(() {});

    return true;
  }
```

also change this in asdas class:

```
factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Todo(
        types: Displaynames.fromJson(json["types"]),
        displaynames: Displaynames.fromJson(json["displaynames"]),
        rows: json["rows"] != null ? (json["rows"] as List).map((x) => Displaynames.fromJson(x)).toList():[],
```